# Canceling UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm currently trying to cancel specific UILocalNotifications associated with objects in my data model. To do this, each data object has a unique identifier, which is an `NSUUID`.

**Create UILocalNotification:**

```
/* Set UILocalNotification */
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.fireDate = date;
        localNotification.alertBody = self.mytextfield.text;
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        NSLog(@"making a notification: %@",[r.uniqueId UUIDString]);
        [localNotification.userInfo setValue:[r.uniqueId UUIDString] forKey:@"uid"];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Yet when I go to delete the notification and print out each notifications contents, the `alertbody` of the notifications are printed correctly but the unique identifier is somehow lost. What's wrong with this implementation?

**Cancel UILocalNotification:**

```
Obj *r = (Obj *)[self.objects[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    /* Cancel UILocalNotification */
    NSArray *scheduleReminders = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    NSLog(@"scheduled.count: %i",(int)scheduleReminders.count); // Correctly prints 3
    for (int i = 0; i < scheduleReminders.count; i++)
    {
        UILocalNotification *notification = scheduleReminders[i];

        NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo;
                NSLog(@"searching through reminders: %i %@ %@ %@",(int)i,[userInfoCurrent objectForKey:@"uid"], notification.alertBody); // Alert body prints correctly

        if ([[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"uid"] isEqualToString:[r.uniqueId UUIDString]])
        {
            NSLog(@"found it");
            //Cancelling local notification
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that userInfo is "nil" by default. You should allocate your own NSDictionary, set uid and then set this dictionary to localNotification.userInfo.